# Distinct Values from multiple arrays into one array

Tags: php, arrays, distinct

I am working on my PHP project where I need to list all genres in database but uniquely. please help me.

```
$q_cat = "SELECT DISTINCT `genres` FROM `movie_meta`";

$ex = mysqli_query($con, $q_cat);
$array = array();
while ($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ex)) {
    foreach($res as $value) {
        $x = rtrim($value,',');
        $array = explode(',', $x);

    }
    print_r($array);    
}
```

I am getting this arrays in output using above code:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Crime
        [2] => Thriller
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Adventure
        [2] => Comedy
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Crime
        [1] => Drama
        [2] => Mystery
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Comedy
        [2] => Crime
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Comedy
        [2] => Science Fiction
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Adventure
        [2] => Fantasy
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Adventure
        [2] => Science Fiction
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Comedy
        [1] => Crime
        [2] => Drama
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Adventure
        [2] => Thriller
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Drama
        [1] => Sport
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Comedy
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Horror
        [1] => Thriller
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Biography
        [1] => Comedy
        [2] => Drama
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Thriller
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Science Fiction
        [2] => Thriller
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Adventure
        [1] => Drama
        [2] => Thriller
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Drama
        [1] => History
        [2] => Thriller
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Animation
        [1] => Comedy
        [2] => Family
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Comedy
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Adventure
        [1] => Animation
        [2] => Comedy
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Drama
        [2] => Thriller
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Adventure
        [2] => Biography
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Horror
        [1] => Science Fiction
        [2] => Thriller
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Adventure
        [2] => Animation
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Adventure
        [1] => Biography
        [2] => Drama
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Adventure
        [1] => Comedy
        [2] => Family
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Drama
        [1] => Mystery
        [2] => Thriller
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Adventure
        [1] => Family
        [2] => Fantasy
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Comedy
        [1] => Drama
        [2] => Romance
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Adventure
        [1] => Drama
        [2] => Science Fiction
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Adventure
        [1] => Science Fiction
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Action
        [1] => Crime
        [2] => Drama
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Comedy
        [1] => Drama
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Science Fiction
        [1] => Thriller
    )
```

I want output like this.

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Action
            [1] => Crime
            [2] => Thriller
            [3] => Adventure
            [4] => Comedy
            [5] => Drama
            [6] => ......
            [7] => ....
        )
```

I mean All Distinct Values from all array into one array.

Comment: you can foreach the array and store into another array with the same name as key, so you can get the unique values

Comment: loop through the main array and create new one

Comment: can you provide code. it'll help me lot.

Comment: show us what you tried yet so far.

Comment: as you said **I am getting this arrays in output** is not a single array.

Comment: You should take da look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization. This does not help your current issue. But IMO your Database Design needs improvemnt

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge()` function.  it will merge two or more array in one

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a single array for all the unique data, store data in the array and make the value as key for getting the unique value. finally use the array_values function to get the values as result.

```
$array = array();
while ($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ex)) {
    foreach($res as $value) {
        $x = rtrim($value,',');
        foreach(explode(',', $x) as $val){
            $array[$val] = $val;
        }
    }
}
print_r(array_values($array));
```

Comment: glad to help, don't forgot to mark this as helpful and also UV.

Answer (score 0):

Make associative array so while making associative array duplicate values will be removed
`foreach($array as $value){
   $temp[$value]=$value;
}`

then remove key by using php function array_values

```
$unique_array= array_values($temp);
print_r($unique_array);
```

You will get this as Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Action
    [1] => Crime
    [2] => Thriller
    [3] => Adventure
    [4] => Comedy
    [5] => Drama
)
```

Comment: No need of array_unique her, cause the unique keys used to store the array.